# Two update operations overriding each other even protected by locking

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a pretty intense parallel update operations that I was trying to avoid overlapping without success yet. And I would like to ask if someone has some idea why this might be failing.

Context: Spring Data, JPA entities, 2 fields of the same entity updated in parallel by different invocations to the same operation.

Here is the portion of the code:

```
@Override @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void processTransaction(PurchaseTransaction newTransaction)
    throws UnableToDetermineCompanyForPurchaseException {
    try {
        ... one slow network i/o operation that takes time    


        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                ...
                // Forcing the locks
                Company company = companyRepository.findOneAndLockForWrite(company.getId());

                if (expirationDate.isAfter(company.getFeatureExpiration(transaction.getFeature()))) {
                    switch (transaction.getFeature()) {
                        case IMAGES: company.setImagesFeatureExpiration(expirationDate); break;
                        case EMPLOYEES: company.setEmployeesFeatureExpiration(expirationDate); break;
                        default:
                            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected feature " + transaction.getFeature());
                    }
                    companyRepository.save(company);
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The concrete problem is that one transaction comes and updates one field (let suppose for example imagesFeatureExpiration) and the transaction that comes immediately after (100ms after) updates the other field (let suppose for example employeesFeatureExpiration) but also overrides the change made by the previous transaction (i.e. overrides imagesFeatureExpiration leaving the previous value).

Currently I moved to direct updates trying to avoid the problem:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Company c SET c.imagesFeatureExpiration = :expiration WHERE c.id = :id")
void setImagesFeatureExpirationById(@Param("id") long id, @Param("expiration") LocalDateTime expiration);
```

but still thinking why this is happening under a transactional, entity locked context, since one of the reads should be locked by the other preventing this to happening.

Comment: Post the code for method findOneAndLockForWrite()

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I set ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ when is ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE